# Why findcontrol("x") ASP.NET method can not find a HTML control that made via javascript runtime?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, server-side, findcontrol

my web page has an optional contact panel that user can add input text for any contact, like cellphone or email,when user click create contact button, it make an input text with attributes like unique id(for example `txtrelat1`) or `runat="server"`(in client-side but web page has an input text with `id="txtrelat0"` by default) and when user click submit button ,calls `register` method in server-side by onserverclick event,
main question is,when i use `form1.FindControl("txtrelat0")`,it's find and i can convert it to `HtmlInputText` but when i want `form1.FindControl("txtrelat1")` it's not find and return null?
thank's all

Comment: You cannot find JavaScript controls via code behind.

Comment: Simply adding the attribute `runat="server"` from the client side doesn't mean that it's going to get picked up. If you're looking for posted values from the client side, you should be able to dig them out of the `Request.Forms` property via the `name` attribute of your text element.

Answer (score 0):

`FindControl` finds server controls in the page or control currently executing. It deals only with server controls. The code behind can still read values posted from the inputs you add. You could call `Request.Form["x"]`.

The downside is that if you add additional controls to the page and then do a postback the server page isn't going to "remember" the elements you added. They'll just disappear after the postback.

Mixing those types of client/server behaviors with webforms isn't fun. You might find it easier to do it with all server controls. Just set `Visible="false"` or `"true"` in your server code in response to server events. Or you could do it all on the client using API calls.

Even though I don't like webforms that much, when I have to work in a webforms project it's often easier to do things the webforms way with server controls.